# Change value of property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm having an issue changing the value of a JSON property.

I want to check if my JSON property is an empty object and if so change the value to null. I figured out how to check if the property is an empty object but I can't figure out how to change the value.

My JSON:

```
{
    "payload": {}
}
```

My goal:

```
{
    "payload": null
}
```

What I have so far:

```
JToken payloadProperty = data["payload"];
if (payloadProperty != null && payloadProperty.Type == JTokenType.Object && !payloadProperty.HasValues)
{
    // WHAT TO PUT HERE TO SET "payload" TO NULL
}
```

Comment: What is the porpouse of this? What do you  want this Json for

Comment: After replacement what do you want to do? Deserialize it? Re-serialize it? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

What is the porpouse of all of this? you can just use string function

```
myJson="{ \"payload\": {} }";

myJson=myJson.Replace("\"payload\": {}", "\"payload\": null");
```

or if you have only payload, or have the same problems with another properties you can try this

```
myJson=myJson.Replace("{}", "null");
```

Comment: I thought about that but I'm not in control of the incoming JSON so I don't know if there could be any leading/trailing/internal spaces. The "{" and "}" could even be on separate lines. That's why I'm using the Newtonsoft library.

Comment: then you have to show the whole class payload. And is you json has only one property payload or something else too?

Comment: That's not necessary. I've already used the JSON.NET library to find the JToken. I just need to find out how to use Newtonsoft's JSON.NET library to set the value to null. String manipulation of the JSON string is not the best way to do it.

Comment: if you have only one object I don't see any need for more complicated algorithm. This  is why you have to post the real json sample. it is the stack overflow rules and you don't want to break them.  It is hard to answer without seeing the real code. You should  not post the question and waist anoher peoples time if you want to answer it  yourself.

Comment: The rest of the JSON isn't relevant. It has no impact on using the JSON.NET library to update that one property.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. I was able to set the "payload" to null directly. I originally thought it was some method or property on some JSON.NET class.

I just did this

```
JToken payloadProperty = data["payload"];
if (payloadProperty != null && payloadProperty.Type == JTokenType.Object)
{
    data["payload"] = null;
}
```

This results in not needing to know the exact string contents which could have extra spaces, etc.